# Integrated WebLogic Server running issue in JDeveloper

Tags: java, xml, oracle, weblogic, jdeveloper

I've been trying to run a simple application using a tutorial in JDeveloper.
I was asked to run the .jsf page I created, using a new username and a password.
After a long time waiting (about 3 minutes) I get the same error again and again:
An error occurred while building the default domain.
Please see this log file for more details:

Log File:

```
C:\Users\skatz\AppData\Roaming\JDeveloper\system12.1.2.0.40.66.68\o.j2ee.adrs\BuildDefaultDomain.log
Label:         JDEVADF_12.1.2.0.0_GENERIC_130608.2330.6668
Product Home:  D:\JDeveloper\jdeveloper\jdev\
Domain:        C:\Users\skatz\AppData\Roaming\JDeveloper\system12.1.2.0.40.66.68\DefaultDomain

BuildDefaultDomain1.py      2014-03-22 18:37:04

cmd.exe /c ""D:\JDeveloper\oracle_common\common\bin\wlst.cmd" "C:\Users\skatz\AppData\Roaming\JDeveloper\system12.1.2.0.40.66.68\o.j2ee.adrs\BuildDefaultDomain1.py""
Process started
wlst > 
wlst > Initializing WebLogic Scripting Tool (WLST) ...
wlst > 
wlst > Welcome to WebLogic Server Administration Scripting Shell
wlst > 
wlst > Type help() for help on available commands
wlst > 
wlst > Creating Default Domain
wlst > [progress] Reading template: /D:/JDeveloper/wlserver/common/templates/wls/wls.jar
wlst > Setting Name to 'DefaultServer'
wlst > Setting ListenAddress to ''
wlst > Setting ListenPort to 7101
wlst > Enabling SSL using port 7102
wlst > Setting domain administrator to 'weblogic'
wlst > Setting domain password.
wlst > [progress] Writing domain: /C:/Users/skatz/AppData/Roaming/JDeveloper/system12.1.2.0.40.66.68/DefaultDomain/
wlst > [progress] Closing template.
wlst > [progress] Reading domain: /C:/Users/skatz/AppData/Roaming/JDeveloper/system12.1.2.0.40.66.68/DefaultDomain/
wlst > [progress] Adding domain extension template: /D:/JDeveloper/jdeveloper/common/templates/jdeveloper/adrs_template.jar
wlst > [progress] Updating domain.
wlst > [progress] Adding domain extension template: /D:/JDeveloper/jdeveloper/common/templates/domains/jsf_template_2.1.jar
wlst > [progress] Updating domain.
wlst > [progress] Adding domain extension template: /D:/JDeveloper/oracle_common/common/templates/wls/oracle.jrf_template_12.1.2.jar
wlst > [progress] Updating domain.
wlst > [progress] Adding domain extension template: /D:/JDeveloper/jdeveloper/common/templates/jdeveloper/adf.fine.logging_12.1.2.jar
wlst > [progress] Updating domain.
wlst > [progress] Adding domain extension template: /D:/JDeveloper/oracle_common/common/templates/wls/oracle.wsmpm_template_12.1.2.jar
wlst > [progress] Updating domain.
wlst > Error: updateDomain() failed. Do dumpStack() to see details.
wlst > Problem invoking WLST - Traceback (innermost last):
wlst >   File "C:\Users\skatz\AppData\Roaming\JDeveloper\system12.1.2.0.40.66.68\o.j2ee.adrs\BuildDefaultDomain1.py", line 112, in ?
wlst >   File "C:\Users\skatz\AppData\Local\Temp\WLSTOfflineIni2422634498251540366.py", line 103, in updateDomain
wlst > 
wlst > Domain Location: C:\Users\skatz\AppData\Roaming\JDeveloper\system12.1.2.0.40.66.68\DefaultDomain
wlst > 
wlst > Reason: Unable to create xml parser
wlst > 
wlst > Exception:
wlst > 
wlst > Unable to create xml parser
wlst > 
wlst > 
wlst >  at com.oracle.cie.domain.script.jython.CommandExceptionHandler.handleException(CommandExceptionHandler.java:55)
wlst > 
wlst >  at com.oracle.cie.domain.script.jython.WLScriptContext.handleException(WLScriptContext.java:1967)
wlst > 
wlst >  at com.oracle.cie.domain.script.jython.WLScriptContext.updateDomain(WLScriptContext.java:604)
wlst > 
wlst >  at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
wlst > 
wlst >  at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
wlst > 
wlst >  at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
wlst > 
wlst >  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
wlst > 
wlst > 
wlst > com.oracle.cie.domain.script.jython.WLSTException: com.oracle.cie.domain.script.jython.WLSTException: com.oracle.cie.domain.script.ScriptException: Domain Extension Application Failed!
wlst > 
wlst > Domain Location: C:\Users\skatz\AppData\Roaming\JDeveloper\system12.1.2.0.40.66.68\DefaultDomain
wlst > 
wlst > Reason: Unable to create xml parser
wlst > 
wlst > Exception:
wlst > 
wlst > Unable to create xml parser
wlst > 
wlst > 
Elapsed time:  106738 ms
```

My first guess was this line- Unable to create xml parser, although almost no information is found about xml parser creation failure in the web.
What am I missing?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Would you be able to provide a few line before and after of line 112 of the "BuildDefaultDomain1.py" and line 103 of "WLSTOfflineIni2422634498251540366.py" (stated in the error)? There you could start diagnosis by understanding what the code is trying to do.

Comment: I was trying to make it clearer with spaces and stuff, sorry about how it looks:
Would you be able to provide a few line before and after of line 112:

if len(templates) > 0:
  print("[progress] Reading domain: " + targetDomain)
  readDomain(targetDomain);

  for t in templates:
    print("[progress] Adding domain extension template: " + t)
    addTemplate(t)
    print("[progress] Updating domain.")
    updateDomain()

  print("[progress] Closing domain.")
  closeDomain()
  
print("*** Domain processing complete ***");  

and line 103:

def updateDomain():
  WLS.updateDomain()

Answer (score 2):

Remove the directory - C:\Users\skatz\AppData\Roaming\JDeveloper\system12.1.2.0.40.66.68\DefaultDomain

Make sure your CLASSPATH environment variable is empty

And try again

Comment: I had to deal with the legacy ADF application implemented in JDeveloper 11g 11.1.1.7.0 and this answer led me to a resolution of the issue. One minor input from me in that regard though. 1. I have used the "set JDEV_USER_DIR= " environment variable to explicitly set the location of the CONFIG folder - the one, where the Integrated Server domain configuration is going to be located. 2. Yes, I had to delete the folder system11.1.1.7.40.64.93 located there along with the tmp folder -- and that solved the issue! The AppData\Roaming folder didn't have a JDeveloper folder at all in my case.

Answer (score 0):

This is a bug in jdeveloper sometimes your jdev will not even start when there is a stuck thread in loading the project components of some applications.

Simple solution is goto this folder-
C:\Users\skatz\AppData\Roaming\JDeveloper\system12.1.2.0.40.66.68\

Delete it. and close the jdev and restart it again, it will recreate the jdev cache and app data so it will take some time while opening it. But it will resolve your problem.

Please note that doing this will delete your jdev prefrences data.

Best Regards